# Nested lists: how to define the size before entering data

Tags: r, nested-forms

I'm rather new to using lists in R. Now I would like to create several nested lists. I already know the number of elements the lists shall contain and now would like to define the size of the lists before entering data into them. 
For the list on the highest level which is to contain 2 elements I used

```
list_example <- vector(mode="list", 2)
```

Now each of the two elements shall contain 3 elements: again lists which again contain lists and so on ...altogether I have 7 levels, that is a tree of 2*3*3*4*2*3*3 combinations. Is there a compact way to define the sizes of such a deeply nested list structure? 
Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: It's not necessary to pre-allocate lists and afaik there is no performance gain if you do it (this is different for other data structures). However, that you see the need probably means that your whole approach could be optimized.

Comment: To further explain: Each entry of a list can contain any kind and size of object. That means R doesn't know how much memory it needs to allocate. You would need to not only pre-allocate the list, but also the objects in it. But that is very cumbersome and there are better strategies available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that using a recursive function.

```
rec.list <- function(len){
    if(length(len) == 1){
        vector("list", len)
    } else {
        lapply(1:len[1], function(...) rec.list(len[-1]))
    }
}

l <- rec.list(c(2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3))
```

Or perhaps with a 7-d list array? It might look bizarre at first, but it is a perfectly valid data structure.

```
l <- vector("list", 2*3*3*4*2*3*3)
dim(l) <- c(2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3)
l[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]] <- "content"
```

Comment: +1 a 7D array is perfect for the situation where you know every node in the list has a fixed number of children. Not enough people know that you can have matrices and arrays of lists, like with the atomic types.

Comment: You're welcome! The beauty of SO is that when you ask "How do I use A to achieve B?" the answer is often "Don't use A, use C", which you hadn't even heard of.

Answer (score 2):

Set some kind of parameters:

```
window_front <- 100
horizon <- 10
```

Create an empty nested list:

```
sub_horizon <- vector("list", 27)

for (i in 1:length(sub_horizon)) {
  sub_horizon[[i]] <- vector("list", window_front)
  for (m in 1:length(sub_horizon[[i]])) {
    sub_horizon[[i]][[m]] <- vector("list", horizon)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple method to declare, for example, a list of 3 nested inside a list of 5:

```
my.list<-lapply(my.list<-vector(mode = 'list',5),function(x) x<-vector(mode='list',3))

summary(my.list)

     Length Class  Mode
[1,] 3      -none- list
[2,] 3      -none- list
[3,] 3      -none- list
[4,] 3      -none- list
[5,] 3      -none- list
```

If you would like to add another nested list,for example 2 slots, just add another lapply, such that:

```
my.list<-lapply(my.list<-vector(mode = 'list',5),function(x) 
      x<-lapply(x<-vector(mode = 'list',3),function(x) 
      x<-vector(mode='list',2)))

summary(my.list)
     Length Class  Mode
[1,] 3      -none- list
[2,] 3      -none- list
[3,] 3      -none- list
[4,] 3      -none- list
[5,] 3      -none- list

summary(my.list[[1]])
     Length Class  Mode
[1,] 2      -none- list
[2,] 2      -none- list
[3,] 2      -none- list
```

Comment: What about if you want to name each of the different levels? Like if the outer part of the list was IDs and then the next level was different levels you tried and then the inner most level was the type of model you fit. Is there a way to modify the above to name the different levels?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems a bit complicated to me. You might want to consider using something like a look-up table that contains the combination of cases for each element:

#### Example

```
id <- seq(2*3*3*4*2*3*3) # a vector of identification values

#create a lookup table
lut <- cbind(id=id, expand.grid(lev1=seq(2), lev2=seq(3), lev3=seq(3), lev4=seq(4), lev5=seq(2), lev6=seq(3), lev7=seq(3)))

list.obj <- vector(mode="list", nrow(lut))

#optional addition of names
names(list.obj) <- paste(lut$lev1, lut$lev2, lut$lev3, lut$lev4, lut$lev5, lut$lev6, lut$lev7, sep=".")
head(list.obj)

#fill in list with data
for(i in seq(list.obj)){
    matching <- i #here you can have some sort of case matching for filling in elements of the list
    list.obj[[matching]] <- runif(10)
}
head(list.obj)
```

I believe this may make your life a whole lot easier when later trying to pick off specific elements for the cases your interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Backlin's great answer to create recursively a nested pre-allocated empty named list.

```
rec.list.named <- function(len, listnames) {
    if(length(len) == 1){
    x <- vector("list", len)
    names(x) <- listnames[[1]]
    x
    } else {
    lapply(split(1:len[1],listnames[1]), function(...) rec.list.named(len[-1], listnames[-1]))
    }
}
```

E.g.

```
rec.list.named(c(1,2), list(c("A"), c("a","b")))
rec.list.named(c(2,3), list(c("A", "B"), c("a","b","c")))
```

Note that this code, unlike Backlin's code, have some unexpected side effects.

```
rec.list.named(c(2,3), list(c("A", "1"), c("a","b","c"))) # Order of the list!
rec.list.named(c(2,3), list(c("A"), c("a","b","c"))) # Size of the list!
```

Also

```
l <- vector("list", 2*3*4)
dim(l) <- c(2, 3, 4)
dimnames(l) <- list(c("a", "b"), c("aa","bb","cc"), c("aaa","bbb","ccc", "ddd"))
l["a","aa", "aaa"] <- "content"
```