# How to preallocate and name nested lists in R

Tags: r, nested-lists

I'm going to be running models and I want to save the output of the individual models to a list so that I can access them later. Each of the individual models will also be run with different sets of parameters and model types so what I'd like to do is preallocate a named nested list to save the outputs of the models. I want the outermost level of the list to be IDs, the next level to be parameter and the inner most level the type of model. With an example of IDs:

```
IDs = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3")
parameter_level = c("100", "200")
model_type = c("type1", "type2", "type3")
named_nested_list
$ID1
 $100
  $type1
    NULL
  $type2
    NULL
  $type3
    NULL
 $200
  $type1
   NULL
...
```

The only way I can figure out how to do this is to create the inner list and the just keep adding more lists to it. Like

```
model_type_list = vector(mode = "list", length = length(model_type)
names(model_type_list) = model_type
parameter_level_list = list('100' = model_type_list, '200' = model_type_list)
named_nested_list = list("ID1" = parameter_level_list, "ID2" = parameter_level_list)
```

Except I have 30 IDs and 5 parameters.

Also, is there another type of data structure that would handle this better? The list is all I know to be able to access each of the underlying models and keeping the components named will help prevent confusion as to which part of the list I'm accessing thanks.

I did read the following but I but I either don't understand the "table lookup" answer means (Marc in the box), the answer by (Sonia) and or how to modify answers by (Adam Lee Perelman) and () to allow me to name the individual components of the list.

[Nested lists: how to define the size before entering data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567172/nested-lists-how-to-define-the-size-before-entering-data)

I also found this question below but this would require me to rename each individual part of the list. Is there any way to name it more programmatically?

[How to set names in a nested list in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458527/how-to-set-names-in-a-nested-list-in-r)

Thanks

Comment: There's an upvoted comment on your first link that says *"It's not necessary to pre-allocate lists and afaik there is no performance gain if you do it (this is different for other data structures). However, that you see the need probably means that your whole approach could be optimized."* So I'm curious why you want to pre-allocate these lists?

Comment: I'd like to be able to access the individual model results later in case I need to extract something else from the model or examine model fit without having to re-run all of the models all over again.

Comment: Sure, but why pre-allocate instead of allocating at the time they are assigned?

Comment: Rather than nested lists, which can be annoying to work with, if I were you I think I'd put metadata in a dataframe and fill the models in in a `list` class column, `model_data = expand.grid(IDs = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3"),
parameter_level = c("100", "200"),
model_type = c("type1", "type2", "type3"))` and then use `mapply` or `purrr::map` or whatever to run the models and store them in another column of the data frame. I don't see what using a nested list structure--especially a pre-allocated one--gains you other than a headache.